# How to find files with ^M from linux using csh

Tags: dos, line-endings

Is there a csh script/command to list all the files in source source tree which have line endings that show up as "^M" in emacs (under linux).

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to easily remove all of these DOS carriage returns, just run "dos2unix" on a file or wildcard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on my answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204765/elegant-way-to-search-for-utf-8-files-with-bom#211855):

```
fgrep -rl `echo -ne '\r'` .
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, justs lists the file names.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -exec grep $'\r' {} +
```

The `$'\r'` probably requires bash to function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -print | xargs grep 'cntl-M$'
```

where cntl-M has been entered by first entering cntl-V