# PHP: show image using readfile failed when using UTF-8

Tags: php, unicode

Im trying to use the php function 'readfile(path_to_image)' to dynamically display an image.
While its working with php script file encoded as ANSI, it fails when the same script file encoded in UTF-8 (or even included in a file that uses UTF-8).
Any idea how to solv this?

Sorry, the code is as follow:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
readfile('C:\wbs\uploads\admin\Koala.jpg');
```

As I said it works when file is ANSI, saving it as UTF-8 and it fails.

Thanks,
David

Comment: What headers are you sending before executing readfile()?

Comment: Unanswerable without seeing some code

Comment: What happens exactly that makes it fail? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: I bet you have a [BOM problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255993/how-do-i-remove-i-from-the-beginning-of-a-file).

Answer (score 4):

One wild guess would be that your IDE stores files as UTF-8 with a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark). The BOM will be interpreted as output by PHP, which will prevent the content-type header from being sent, and everything goes pear shaped from there.

You should be encountering `output already sent` warnings if this is the case. Try turning error reporting on if you see nothing.

If this is the case, saving the file without the BOM would solve it.

Comment: Thanks Pekka,
If it is so, what ide can I use to get rid of the BOM?

Comment: @David the tool that you are using should offer saving the file without a BOM.