# Getting session_start() warning for my newly registered domain

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I have newly registered my domain and everything is working fine but when i use session_start() on my php pages i get this warning

`Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at D:\inetpub\vhosts\mywebsite.com\httpdocs\sample\new.php:1) in D:\inetpub\vhosts\mywebsite.com\httpdocs\sample\new.php on line 3`

```
 `Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session 
  cache limiter - 
  headers already sent (output started at        
  D:\inetpub\vhosts\mywebsite.com\httpdocs\sample\new.php:1) in 
  D:\inetpub\vhosts\mywebsite.com\httpdocs\sample\new.php on line 3`
```

What do i need to do to get rid of this warning I an unable to use session_start() on my php pages.please help me in fixing this.any help is greatly appreciated.Thanks

**Update** This is my index and profile.php pages

my index.php page

```
     <?php
          session_start();
       ?>
               <!doctype HTML> some html coding goes on
```

my profile.php page

```
 <?php
            session_start();
    $con = mysql_connect('some', 'some', 'some');       
    $email = $_POST["nemail"];
    $password = $_POST["npassword"];
    $month = $_POST["nmonth"];
    $dayy = $_POST["ndate"];
    $yearr = $_POST["nyear"];
    $gender = $_POST["ngender"];
    $sname = $_POST["sname"];
    $status = $_POST["nrelation"];
    $rannum = 1;
    $birthday = $month . " " . $dayy . " " . $yearr;
    mysql_select_db("users_names");
            $_SESSION['unique']= $rannum;
  ?>
```

I get this error when i jump to profile.php from index.php

`Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at D:\inetpub\vhosts\website.com\httpdocs\sample\profile.php:1) in D:\inetpub\vhosts\website.com\httpdocs\sample\profile.php on line 3`

I want to start session on index page but i want to assign values to session variables in profile.php page thats what i did in profile.php in the last line

Comment: Nothing is there in my code i just used session_start() in my page thats it i see this error nothing else in my code and when i remove the session_start() i dont get this warning

Comment: So it's nothing with your code but when you modify it the error don't appear... strange... maybe is there something with your code... can you post it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your code posted it will be simplier.

The cookies (session_start use cookies) can only be sent with the HTTP headers. If you've already done a `echo` or called the function `headers()` before the `session_start()` function, you can't send cookies anymore so you can't start the session, because the headers are already sent.

Comment: I guess you are right i used headers in my page im not sure where i used let me check it and Thanks

Comment: @niko          I told you - check for spaces, new line symbols before the <?php in new.php. If you do not see anything (and the first output is on the first line of this file) then there is a BOM record.

Comment: @niko          You definitely have BOM - remove it from all files. To check whether you have it or not - download file by ftp and open in any normal text editor (like Notepad++ or whatever you use for scripts editing)

Comment: The session_start() is the first function you call, check there is **nothing** before the `<?php` markup. Your error says that the output began on your `profile.php` page at line 1. Start checking this page.

Comment: @BlackCharly Your awesome there was spaces before <?php oh god! thanks alot! it works now i removed those spaces

Comment: @niko          I wrote you about spaces too and thought that you've checked it already.

Answer (score 4):

Are your php scripts in UTF (I mean content of php files is in unicode encoding)? Did you remove BOM record in that case? Or, perhaps, you have empty space(s) before opening php tag

[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

> For instance in PHP, the existence of a BOM will cause the page to
>   begin output before the initial code is interpreted, causing problems
>   if the page is trying to send custom HTTP headers (which must be set
>   before output begins).

Comment: Yes they are UTF 8 and what is BOM

Comment: @niko          I also gave a link to Wiki  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark  it is set of bytes at the beginning of the file. It will be the first output to the browser. Cite from Wiki: For instance in PHP, the existence of a BOM will cause the page to begin output before the initial code is interpreted, causing problems if the page is trying to send custom HTTP headers (which must be set before output begins).

Comment: okay may be i dont know but how do i remove bom can you explain in your answer please

Comment: @niko          You have either to download everything to your computer and to remove BOM manually in the any normal text editor or to use any utility on your computer or one, that you can run on your server, to fix the files. And look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255993/how-do-i-remove-i-from-the-beginning-of-a-file

Comment: @niko          try it on just one file and check the result. Notepad++ easily removes BOM (Encoding in menu). Remove it, upload back to the server, call it through the browser and look at result. If warning disappears - you've found the reason.

Comment: Thanks cheery but all i can do is i can give you +1 but it was his answer open my eyes

Comment: @niko          it is up to you. I wrote "Or, perhaps, you have empty space(s) before opening php tag" at my first posting. I do not care about points - I just like to help )

Comment: well i appreciate your help and im really thankful to u thanks cheery

Answer (score 1):

Make sure absolutely nothing - not even whitespace - is output before the call to `session_start()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable output beffering to be able to use session. Use [ob_start()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) function somewhere in the beginning of you php code

Comment: @nikc.org : With ob_start() enabled at script begining, the headers aren't directly sent and the session can be started at every point of the script, so it has to do with the error.

Comment: @BlackCharly unless the file has a BOM at the beginning. Then all the output buffering in the world will have no effect whatsoever. Using output buffering can be _a solution_, but it is not an explanation to what the source of the problem is.