# While parsing json, JSONException: Value ï»¿

Tags: android, json

I'm parsing json and something is going wrong. I get this error in LogCat:

```
04-04 12:51:24.283: E/JSON Parser(9077): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value ï»¿ of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Here is my function with I'm parsing the json:

```
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
                JSONObject theJSON;
                try {

                    // Getting Array of albums
                    theJSON = json.getJSONObject("json");
                    albums = theJSON.getJSONArray(TAG_ALBUMS);
                    // looping through All albums
                    for (int i = 0; i < albums.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = albums.getJSONObject(i);
                        String album_id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String album_name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String album_singer = c.getString(TAG_SINGER);
                        String album_mix = c.getString(TAG_MIX);
                        String album_genre = c.getString(TAG_GENRE);
                        String album_thumb = "http://nelu.burduja.com/musica/cover_image/"
                                + c.getString(TAG_THUMB);
                        albumsArray.add(new Albums(album_id, album_name,
                                album_singer, album_genre, album_mix,
                                album_thumb, songsArray));
                        sngs = c.getJSONArray(TAG_SONGS);
                        // getting songs for the album
                        songsArray=new ArrayList<Songs>();
                        for (int j = 0; j < sngs.length(); j++) {
                            JSONObject songs = sngs.getJSONObject(j);
                            String song_artist = songs.getString(TAG_SONG_ARTIST);
                            String song_mp3 = songs.getString(TAG_SONG_MP3);
                            String song_mp4 = songs.getString(TAG_SONG_MP4);
                            String song_thumb = songs.getString(TAG_SONG_THUMB);
                            String song_title = songs.getString(TAG_SONG_TITLE);
                            songsArray.add(new Songs(song_title, song_artist,
                                    song_mp3, song_mp4, song_thumb));

                        }
                        albumsArray.get(i).setSongs(songsArray);
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

And this is my json output:

```
     {
   "json":{
      "albums":[
         {
            "id":"1",
            "name":"Summer hits",
            "singer":"",
            "genre":"Trance",
            "mix":"yes",
            "thumb":"cov_515aa81ff03a3.jpeg",
            "songs":[
               {
                  "song":"Song 1",
                  "artist":"Singer 1",
                  "mp3":"",
                  "mp4":"http://youtu.be/Jdra3HU6w0I",
                  "thumb":"snwith_515bf52a1d8e2.jpeg"
               },
               {
                  "song":"Song 3 ",
                  "artist":"Singer 3",
                  "mp3":"",
                  "mp4":"",
                  "thumb":"snwith_515bf55476e2c.jpeg"
               },
               {
                  "song":"Song 4",
                  "artist":"Singer 4",
                  "mp3":"",
                  "mp4":"",
                  "thumb":"snwith_515c14974562f.jpeg"
               },
               {
                  "song":"Super hit",
                  "artist":"Gherghe Topa",
                  "mp3":"with_515c34d1bbde7.mp3",
                  "mp4":"",
                  "thumb":"snwith_515c34d1aeee1.jpeg"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "id":"2",
            "name":"Rock In",
            "singer":"Limp Bizkit",
            "genre":"Pop",
            "mix":"no",
            "thumb":"cov_515ab5aff24fe.jpeg",
            "songs":[
               {
                  "song":"In the end",
                  "artist":"Linkin park",
                  "mp3":"",
                  "mp4":"",
                  "thumb":""
               },
               {
                  "song":"December",
                  "artist":"Linkin park",
                  "mp3":"",
                  "mp4":"",
                  "thumb":""
               },
               {
                  "song":"Rock in baby",
                  "artist":"Linkin park",
                  "mp3":"",
                  "mp4":"",
                  "thumb":""
               },
               {
                  "song":"Bang head",
                  "artist":"Linkin park",
                  "mp3":"",
                  "mp4":"",
                  "thumb":""
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "id":"3",
            "name":"Hybrid Theory",
            "singer":"Linkin park",
            "genre":"Pop",
            "mix":"no",
            "thumb":"cov_515ab6010a98a.jpeg",
            "songs":[

            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

and here is my full logCat error log:

```
04-04 12:51:24.283: E/JSON Parser(9077): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value ï»¿ of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
04-04 12:51:24.283: W/dalvikvm(9077): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a7e1f8)
04-04 12:51:24.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9077): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
04-04 12:51:24.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9077): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-04 12:51:24.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9077):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
04-04 12:51:24.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9077):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
04-04 12:51:24.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9077):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
04-04 12:51:24.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9077):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
04-04 12:51:24.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9077):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-04 12:51:24.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9077):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
04-04 12:51:24.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9077):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
04-04 12:51:24.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9077):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
04-04 12:51:24.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9077):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-04 12:51:24.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9077): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-04 12:51:24.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9077):     at com.myapp.activities.LatestAlbums$5.doInBackground(LatestAlbums.java:196)
04-04 12:51:24.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9077):     at com.myapp.activities.LatestAlbums$5.doInBackground(LatestAlbums.java:1)
04-04 12:51:24.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9077):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
04-04 12:51:24.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9077):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-04 12:51:24.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9077):     ... 5 more
```

I've noticed if I manually clear the json output from new rows('\n) and empty spaces between objects and arrays it works ok. Anybody has an idea how can I solve this problem?

Comment: check this line doInBackground(LatestAlbums.java:196)

Comment: @RajeshCP that line is this one: theJSON = json.getJSONObject("json"); and I think that one is ok, or maybe not:)

Comment: from above what are required for u??

Comment: @SubbaReddyPolamReddy I need everything from the json

Comment: json might be null check it

Comment: Similar question [discussed here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255993/how-do-i-remove-i-from-the-beginning-of-a-file)..might solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The characters you see " ï»¿" is the [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) so you should check your encoding (utf8 with or without BOM).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That was the problem. The solution in implementing a class in the JsonParser that i found here http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-handle-utf8-file-with-bom.html