# <U+FEFF> in php response

Tags: php, linux

I echo "OK" from php file, and when I call url from Linux console gets it like this:

```
<U+FEFF>
OK
```

PHP server is also on Linux.

How to get just OK?

Thanks.

Comment: it's a Byte order mark - or BOM. Also an incredibly common problem/question.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to tell your editor not to use BOM. As described in this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255993/how-do-i-remove-i-from-the-beginning-of-a-file) question.