# Unknown option 'ï»¿' in line 1 of file 'proguard-project.txt'

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard

I am getting following exception when I try to build my project in release mode. I have enabled proguard.

> Proguard returned with error code 1. See console proguard.ParseException: Unknown option 'ï»¿' in line 1 of file 'my project path/proguard-project.txt'

After some search I was able to guess that its some sort of `Byte Order Mark or BOM` See: [How do I remove ï»¿ from the beginning of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255993/how-do-i-remove-i-from-the-beginning-of-a-file)

But after Googling, it seems that I am the only one who is having this issue. How Can I solve this issue?

Comment: The solution is described in the link you provided, have you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to remove BOM from file using following source code copied from [this](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=257) site:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Detect and remove Byte Order Marks (BOMs) from text files saved with a
 * Unicode encoding.
 * 
 * <P>
 * Dev tool only. If you use this tool to remove BOMs, please ensure you have
 * made a backup.
 * 
 * <P>
 * This class assumes the UTF-8 encoding for the BOM, but is easily changed to
 * handle any encoding. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark for
 * more info. JDK 5+.
 */
public final class BomDetector {

/** Run the tool against a root directory. */
public static void main(String... aArgs) throws IOException {
    BomDetector bom = new BomDetector(
            "J:\\Kepler\\ArbisoftWorkspace22Aug13\\Main", ".txt", ".jsp",
            ".jspf", ".tag", ".html", ".css", ".xml", ".js", ".sql", ".tld");

    int count = 0;
    for (String file : bom.findBOMs()) {
        log(file);
        ++count;
    }
    log("Number of files with BOM:" + count);

    for (String file : bom.removeBOMs()) {
        log("Removed BOM from: " + file);
    }

}

public BomDetector(String aRootDirectory, String... aFileExtensions) {
    fRootDir = new File(aRootDirectory);
    fExtensions = Arrays.asList(aFileExtensions);
    if (!fRootDir.exists() || fRootDir.isFile()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Root directory not valid.");
    }
}

/** Find files with BOMs under the given root directory. Return their names. */
public List<String> findBOMs() throws IOException {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (File textFile : findTextFilesBeneath(fRootDir)) {
        if (startsWithBOM(textFile)) {
            result.add(textFile.getCanonicalPath());
        }
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * Find and remove BOMs from files under the given root directory.
 * Overwrites files. Return the names of the affected files.
 */
public List<String> removeBOMs() throws IOException {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String bomFile : findBOMs()) {
        stripBomFrom(bomFile);
        result.add(bomFile);
    }
    return result;
}

// PRIVATE
private File fRootDir;
private List<String> fExtensions;

/** Different encodings will have different BOMs. This is for UTF-8. */
private final int[] BYTE_ORDER_MARK = { 239, 187, 191 };

private static void log(Object aThing) {
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(aThing));
}

private List<File> findTextFilesBeneath(File aStartingDir)
        throws IOException {
    List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
    File[] filesAndDirs = aStartingDir.listFiles();
    List<File> filesDirs = Arrays.asList(filesAndDirs);
    for (File file : filesDirs) {
        if (isTextFile(file)) {
            result.add(file);
        }
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            // recursive call!!
            List<File> deeperList = findTextFilesBeneath(file);
            result.addAll(deeperList);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private boolean isTextFile(File aFile) throws IOException {
    boolean result = false;
    String fileName = aFile.getCanonicalPath();
    int finalDot = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (finalDot > -1) {
        String extension = fileName.substring(finalDot);
        result = fExtensions.contains(extension);
    }
    return result;
}

private boolean startsWithBOM(File aTextFile) throws IOException {
    boolean result = false;
    if (aTextFile.length() < BYTE_ORDER_MARK.length)
        return false;
    // open as bytes here, not characters
    int[] firstFewBytes = new int[BYTE_ORDER_MARK.length];
    InputStream input = null;
    try {
        input = new FileInputStream(aTextFile);
        for (int index = 0; index < BYTE_ORDER_MARK.length; ++index) {
            firstFewBytes[index] = input.read(); // read a single byte
        }
        result = Arrays.equals(firstFewBytes, BYTE_ORDER_MARK);
    } finally {
        input.close();
    }
    return result;
}

private void stripBomFrom(String aTextFile) throws IOException {
    File bomFile = new File(aTextFile);
    long initialSize = bomFile.length();
    long truncatedSize = initialSize - BYTE_ORDER_MARK.length;
    byte[] memory = new byte[(int) (truncatedSize)];
    InputStream input = null;
    try {
        input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(bomFile));
        input.skip(BYTE_ORDER_MARK.length);
        int totalBytesReadIntoMemory = 0;
        while (totalBytesReadIntoMemory < truncatedSize) {
            int bytesRemaining = (int) truncatedSize
                    - totalBytesReadIntoMemory;
            int bytesRead = input.read(memory, totalBytesReadIntoMemory,
                    bytesRemaining);
            if (bytesRead > 0) {
                totalBytesReadIntoMemory = totalBytesReadIntoMemory
                        + bytesRead;
            }
        }
        overwriteWithoutBOM(memory, bomFile);
    } finally {
        input.close();
    }
    File after = new File(aTextFile);
    long finalSize = after.length();
    long changeInSize = initialSize - finalSize;
    if (changeInSize != BYTE_ORDER_MARK.length) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Change in file size: " + changeInSize
                + " Expected change: " + BYTE_ORDER_MARK.length);
    }
}

private void overwriteWithoutBOM(byte[] aBytesWithoutBOM, File aTextFile)
        throws IOException {
    OutputStream output = null;
    try {
        output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(aTextFile));
        output.write(aBytesWithoutBOM);
    } finally {
        output.close();
    }
}
}
```