# XML Deserialization Error - Processing instructions and DTDs are not supported

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xml-serialization

I have been given an XML file and an XSD file.  I am trying to validate the XML against the XSD and then, using `Serialization`, load the the XML into an object.

I have the validation working as expected but when I try to `DeserializeDocToObj` I get the following error.

```
There was an error deserializing the object of type 
Aaa.Bbb.Common.DataTypes.SurveyGroup. Processing instructions
(other than the XML declaration) and DTDs are not supported. 
Line 1, position 2.
```

I have no idea what this means and all I have read is not really helping.

The header in the XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns="http://www.mydomain.co.uk/srm/mscc" 
           targetNamespace="http://www.mydomain.co.uk/srm/mscc" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified" 
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:element name="SurveyGroup">
```

The header in the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="mscc4_cctv.xsl"?>
<SurveyGroup xmlns="http://www.mydomain.co.uk/srm/mscc" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xsi:schemaLocation="
              http://www.mydomain.co.uk/srm/mscc 
              http://www.mydomain.co.uk/srm/schemas/mscc4_cctv.xsd">
<Survey>
```

Deserialization Code:

```
    public T DeserializeDocToObj(string fileLocation)
    {
        T returnObj;

        using (FileStream reader = new FileStream(fileLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
            returnObj = (T)ser.ReadObject(reader);
        }

        return returnObj;
    }
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Any chance you're file contains the dreaded BOM (byte order mark)?

Comment: @MarvinSmit Sorry I am still very much a beginner at this. How would I know?  Is there a quick way for me look for it?  Would XMLSpy tell me?

Comment: XMLSpy won't tell you, use a dos prompt and use "type filename". I you see weird characters before the xml starts, you're file on disk contains the "BOM". You'll have to 'skip' that BOM before trying to deserialize. (i.e. do a reader.Seek(4, seekOrigin.Begin);) before you call the deserialize.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255993/how-do-i-remove-i-from-the-beginning-of-a-file for more details on that BOM thingy ;

Comment: @MarvinSmit thanks for the responses.  It turned out there was no BOM and I didn't find a solution to that problem really.  However I changed the serialiser from `DataContractSerializer` to `XmlSerializer` and now have what I need (or thereabouts)

Answer (score 2):

[Create](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.create(v=vs.110).aspx) an [`XmlReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader(v=vs.110).aspx) with the correct [`XmlReaderSettings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings(v=vs.110).aspx) and call [`DataContractSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer(v=vs.110).aspx).[`ReadObject(XmlReader)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms573849(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of [`DataContractSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer(v=vs.110).aspx).[`ReadObject(Stream)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms574047(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(fileName, new XmlReaderSettings { IgnoreProcessingInstructions = true }))
{
    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
    return (T)serializer.ReadObject(reader);
}
```

The [`XmlReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader(v=vs.110).aspx) used by [`DataContractSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer(v=vs.110).aspx).[`Read(Stream)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms574047(v=vs.110).aspx) does not [`IgnoreProcessingInstructions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.ignoreprocessinginstructions(v=vs.110).aspx).  [`DataContractSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer(v=vs.110).aspx).[`Read(Stream)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms574047(v=vs.110).aspx) calls [`XmlDictionaryReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldictionaryreader(v=vs.110).aspx).[`CreateTextReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa346767(v=vs.110).aspx) (see the [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Runtime.Serialization/System/Runtime/Serialization/XmlObjectSerializer.cs,e05b64cee0dd3840)) which creates a  [`XmlUTF8TextReader`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Runtime.Serialization/System/Xml/XmlUTF8TextReader.cs) (see the [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Runtime.Serialization/System/Xml/XmlDictionaryReader.cs,092307d9a6870095)) which does not accept [`XmlReaderSettings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings(v=vs.110).aspx).

Apparently the default behaviour is to crap on (unknown) [processing instructions](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-pi).  And the string `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="mscc4_cctv.xsl"?>` is a processing instruction as [C.M. Sperberg-McQueen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1477421/c-m-sperberg-mcqueen) [states](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20381196/814206).

Answer (score 1):

The string `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="mscc4_cctv.xsl"?>` is a processing instruction.  Your software is telling you it cannot handle processing instructions in its input.  This means that your software appears not to be an XML parser; you need either to restrict your input to the subset of XML it can handle, or get a real parser.

Comment: Can someone cite the part of the standard that defines "if the software cannot handle processing instructions it is not an XML parser" (https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-pi doesn't make any requirements about handling PIs).

Comment: I used the term "XML parser" in the ordinary-language sense of "a parser that parses XML documents", not as a term involving conformance.  That XML documents can contain processing instructions follows from section 2.1 of the spec and productions [1], [27], and [16] (and others).  I have no idea why I mentioned parsers, though, when OP's problem is clearly serialization.