# Weird characters added to first column name after reading a toad-exported csv file

Tags: r, csv, toad

Whenever I read a `csv` file in R (`read.csv("file_name.csv")`) that was exported using toad, the first column name is preceded by the following characters "**ï..**". Also, opening the csv file in excel or notepad++ shows up correctly (without the preceding characters). This is a hassle as my workaround has been to rename the column after each read. 
Thanks for any fix to this issue!

Edit:
The export was created in Toad by right-clicking on the result set of a query and selecting 
 'Quick Export -> File -> CSV File'

More details per comment:

```
head(readLines('test_file.csv'),n=3)`<br>
[1] "ï»¿ID,LOCATION" "12021,1204" "12281,1204"
```

Comment: Can you include the results of `head(readLines('file_name.csv'),n=3)`?

Comment: r2evans, just ran your code and uploaded it, first time I see the reversed interrogation mark. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: This tells me it is not an R issue. There are ways to work around this, but R is behaving correctly here.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Try this:

```
d <- read.csv("test_file.csv", fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM")
```

This works in R 3.0.0+ and removes the BOM if present in the file (common for files generated from Microsoft applications: Excel, SQL server)

Comment: This worked for me too! The original csv file was created in Excel (Mac), and I was trying to open it in R (Windows).

Comment: I realize this is an old thread, but I just wanted to mention that this worked for me as well.

Comment: in Python3x changed it to encoding = 'UTF-8',

Comment: It works when I change encoding to `'UTF-8-SIG'` in Python.

Answer (score 16):

I know this is a very old question, but the easiest solution I have found, is to use NotePad++. Open the CSV file in NotePad++, click "Encoding" and select "Encode in UTF-8" and save the file. It removes the BOM, and the original code should work.

Answer (score 5):

I recently ran into this with both the clipboard and Microsoft Excel

With the ever-increasing multi-lingual content used for data science there simply isn't a safe way to assume utf-8 any longer (in my case excel assumed UTF-16 because most of my data included Traditional Chinese (Mandarin?).

According to [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/encoding/byte-order-mark) the following BOMs are used in Windows:

```
|----------------------|-------------|-----------------------|
| Encoding             | Bom         | Python encoding kwarg |
|----------------------|-------------|-----------------------|
| UTF-8                | EF BB BF    | 'utf-8'               |
| UTF-16 big-endian    | FE FF       | 'utf-16-be'           |
| UTF-16 little-endian | FF FE       | 'utf-16-le'           |
| UTF-32 big-endian    | 00 00 FE FF | 'utf-32-be'           |
| UTF-32 little-endian | FF FE 00 00 | 'utf-32-le'           |
|----------------------|-------------|-----------------------|
```

I came up with the following approach that seems to work well to detect encoding using the Byte Order Mark at the start of the file:

```py
def guess_encoding_from_bom(filename, default='utf-8'):
    msboms = dict((bom['sig'], bom) for bom in (
        {'name': 'UTF-8', 'sig': b'\xEF\xBB\xBF', 'encoding': 'utf-8'},
        {'name': 'UTF-16 big-endian', 'sig': b'\xFE\xFF', 'encoding':
            'utf-16-be'},
        {'name': 'UTF-16 little-endian', 'sig': b'\xFF\xFE', 'encoding':
            'utf-16-le'},
        {'name': 'UTF-32 big-endian', 'sig': b'\x00\x00\xFE\xFF', 'encoding':
            'utf-32-be'},
        {'name': 'UTF-32 little-endian', 'sig': b'\xFF\xFE\x00\x00',
            'encoding': 'utf-32-le'}))

    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        sig = f.read(4)
        for sl in range(3, 0, -1):
            if sig[0:sl] in msboms:
                return msboms[sig[0:sl]]['encoding']
        return default


# Example using python csv module
def excelcsvreader(path, delimiter=',',
                doublequote=False, quotechar='"', dialect='excel',
                escapechar='\\', fileEncoding='UTF-8'):
    filepath = os.path.expanduser(path)
    fileEncoding = guess_encoding_from_bom(filepath, default=fileEncoding)
    if os.path.exists(filepath):
        # ok let's open it and parse the data
        with open(filepath, 'r', encoding=fileEncoding) as csvfile:
            csvreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=delimiter,
                doublequote=doublequote, quotechar=quotechar, dialect=dialect,
                escapechar='\\')
            for (rnum, row) in enumerate(csvreader):
                yield (rnum, row)
```

I realize that this requires opening the file for reading twice (once binary and once as encoded text) but the API doesn't really make it easy to do otherwise in this particular case.

At any rate, I think this is a bit more robust than simply assuming utf-8 and obviously the automatic encoding detection isn't working so...

Answer (score 2):

After researching this further, it has to do with BOM (Byte Order Mark) added characters. Apparently cannot use Quick Export, but the Data Export Wizard instead as it allows setting the file encoding. It worked for my by setting it to Western European(Windows) instead of unicode utf-8.

See [How do I remove ï»¿ from the beginning of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255993/how-do-i-remove-i-from-the-beginning-of-a-file)

Comment: This issue went away after upgrading to newer version (Toad Data Point 3.4.0.2038)

Comment: Worked for me! I was importing a csv created with Excel 2016.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Just wanted to add to the solutions proposed above that you can avoid having BOM added in the beginning of the file by:

- creating csv file from notepad or Notepad++ and then saving it with '.csv' extention;
- also some IDEs, e.g. PyCharm, have built-in functionality for this mark removal:
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem. My code is:

```
from csv import reader
def parse_csv():
    with open(source_dir, 'r') as read_obj:
        csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
        for row in csv_reader:
            print(row)
```

`source_dir` is the path to my CSV file.

The solution for this problem is open your CSV file with "Notepad++". You will have "Encoding" option on top of it. From Encoding, select "UTF-8" and save the file.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue.
Solved by:
Instead of saving the excel file in "CSV UTF-8", I saved it as simple "CSV".