# Why is 'ï..' at the front of the first colname when imported a csv into r?

Tags: r, read.csv

Why is 'ï..' at the front of the first colname when imported a csv into r?

This happens whenever I have a csv saved via excel and then do read.csv() in r. What causes this behavior?

Dput:

structure(list(ï..Species = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L,
9L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L,
5L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 2L), Country = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L,
4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L,
5L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-29L))

Comment: It would help to see your code, your input data and your expected output.  Otherwise we are only guessing.

Comment: Please show your code. Are you writing the CSV file using R as well, or only reading it?

Comment: I am only reading a csv in r. The file is saved in excel as a csv. The code is just 'read.csv(filename.csv)

Comment: @Bohnston that makes it easier to post your actual code and an example of your file. Post the **actual code** that produces what you describe, and the **actual** output. Not something like it. Don't expect people to try to reproduce what you claim. It's quite obvious others *don'* have the same issue.

Comment: If the file is a Unicode file with a BOM, it doesn't start with `i` at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please review previous answer here regarding weird characters when importing data from Excel:  [Weird characters added to first column name after reading a toad-exported csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974765/weird-characters-added-to-first-column-name-after-reading-a-toad-exported-csv-fi?rq=1)

Comment: You should explain why this is relevant - the file may be a Unicode file with a BOM. The solution is to use the correct file encoding in `read_csv`

Comment: This was the reason why, I added the correct file encoding and the strange character goes.