# unrecognized character in header of csv

Tags: python, csv

```
import csv

def readCSV(filename, begin_date="01/07/2020", end_date="30/09/2020"):
    file = open(filename)
    csvreader = csv.reader(file)
    header = []
    header = next(csvreader)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    raw_load_data = readCSV("Total_load_2020.csv")
    raw_forecast_data = readCSV("Total_load_forecast_2020.csv")
```

The data follows csv (downloaded online) and looks like follow:

```
RowDate,RowTime,TotalLoadForecast
01/01/2020,00:00,8600.52
01/01/2020,00:15,8502.06
01/01/2020,00:30,8396.45
...
```

But the output contains some weird characters (non-existing in data):

```
['ï»¿RowDate', 'RowTime', 'TotalLoad']
['ï»¿RowDate', 'RowTime', 'TotalLoadForecast']
```

Of course, I can easily remove it. But why does that happen in the first place?

Comment: It looks like your file has a Unicode byte-order marker at the beginning.  I suggest you do `file.seek(3)` immediately after opening it.  You could check the first byte to see if it is 0xEF, 0xFE, or 0xFF.

Comment: FWIW, `pandas.read_csv` can download CSV files into a dataframe for you (and correctly parses header rows)

Comment: Same problem as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974765/weird-characters-added-to-first-column-name-after-reading-a-toad-exported-csv-fi

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes, I gave it a try in the past before. But can it do something post-processing. It's returning a dictionary. What if I need to process specific line of rows

Comment: Pandas returns a dataframe, not a dictionary, but yes, it can do as much processing as you want (such as filtering datetime objects)

Comment: That's a BOM, represented in Windows's CP1252 encoding; see a solution below.

Comment: @Marc-AlexandruBaetica, it seems like a different problem, to me. BOM for sure, but different encoding, and different language (Python, not R).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's a BOM, `U+FEFF BYTE ORDER MARK`.  OP's file is probably encoded UTF-8, but OP appears to be decoding it as CP-1252.

I say that because the three-byte sequence for a UTF-8-encoded BOM is `\xEF\xBB\xBF` and appears as `ï»¿` when (wrongly?) decoded as CP-1252[^1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Byte_order_marks_by_encoding):

| Encoding | Representation (hexadecimal) | Representation (decimal) | Bytes as CP1252 characters |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UTF-8 | `EF BB BF` | `239 187 191` | `ï»¿` |

Here's how to mock up OP's data with a leading BOM, from a BSD shell:

```sh
% echo -e '\xEF\xBB\xBFRowDate,RowTime,TotalLoadForecast
01/01/2020,00:00,8600.52
01/01/2020,00:15,8502.06
01/01/2020,00:30,8396.45' > sample.csv
```

and confirm it's there with `less sample.csv`:

```
<U+FEFF>RowDate,RowTime,TotalLoadForecast
01/01/2020,00:00,8600.52
01/01/2020,00:15,8502.06
01/01/2020,00:30,8396.45
sample.csv (END)
```

Less is correctly interpreting the three UTF-8 bytes as the Unicode code-point `U+FEFF`.

If OP still needs to read this file as CP-1252, they can try with the following... but I think they'll get errors because it doesn't actually seem like it is CP-1252:

```py
import csv

with open('sample.csv', 'r', newline='', encoding='cp1252') as f:
    # Read the first 3 bytes
    leading_bytes = f.read(3)

    if (leading_bytes != 'ï»¿'):
        f.seek(0)  #  Not a BOM, reset stream to beginning of file
    else:
        pass       # skip BOM

    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

But, I really think this file should be decoded as UTF-8:

```
with open('sample.csv', 'r', newline='') as f:  # utf-8 is the default encoding
    # Read the first (decoded) Unicode code point
    first_unicode_char = f.read(1)

    if (first_unicode_char != '\ufeff'):
        f.seek(0) #  Not a BOM, reset stream to beginning of file
```

or, let Python handle the guesswork and eliminate a BOM if it exists, with the `utf_8_sig` decoder:

```py
with open('sample.csv', 'r', newline='', encoding='utf_8_sig') as f:
```

Answer (score 1):

Just update line "file = open(filename)" to "file = open(filename, encoding='utf_8_sig')"

```html
def readCSV(filename, begin_date="01/07/2020", end_date="30/09/2020"):
    file = open(filename, encoding='utf_8_sig')
    csvreader = csv.reader(file)
    header = []
    header = next(csvreader)
```