# How do I ignore a byte order marker from a while read loop in zsh

Tags: macos, shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I need to verify that all images mentioned in a csv are present inside a folder. I wrote a small shell script for that

```
#!/bin/zsh
red='\033[0;31m'
color_Off='\033[0m'

csvfile=$1
imgpath=$2

cat $csvfile | while IFS=, read -r filename rurl
do
    if [ -f "${imgpath}/${filename}" ]
    then
        echo -n
    else
        echo -e "$filename ${red}MISSING${color_Off}"
    fi
done
```

My CSV looks something like

```
Image1.jpg,detail-1
Image2.jpg,detail-1
Image3.jpg,detail-1
```

The csv was created by excel.

Now all 3 images are present in `imgpath` but for some reason my output says

```
Image1.jpg MISSING
```

Upon using `zsh -x` to run the script i found that my CSV file has a BOM at the very beginning making the image name as `\ufeffImage1.jpg` which is causing the whole issue.

How can I ignore a BOM(byte-order marker) in a while read operation?

Comment: You probably have DOS line endings. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/45772525/1745001. Could also just be trailing white space I suppose. Btw, your error message would be  more useful if you also printed the csv name and line number, as well as the file name that it thinks is missing.

Comment: What does `zsh -x yourscript` say in the logs? As Ed says, it's probably DOS line endings; but that should be visible in trace output.

Comment: (as an aside: if an answer that broke on zsh and only worked on bash wouldn't be acceptable, don't use the bash tag; they're very different shells, and not mutually compatible in either direction)

Comment: How do you run the script? What's `$imgpath` set to?

Comment: I run using the following command `./imageFinder.sh /Users/belphegor21/Documents/image.csv /Users/belphegor21/Documents/Images`

Comment: It works well for me. Try doing `dos2unix /Users/belphegor21/Documents/image.csv` as others suggested.

Comment: zsh -x gave me the answer. I was not aware of that command. Thanks @CharlesDuffy. My csv was created in excel so maybe something went wrong there. The file has `\ufeff` at the very beginning making the image name as `\ufeffImage1.jpg` which it can't find. Deleting that fixed it.

Comment: Ahh, great. That's what's called a byte-order marker.

Comment: ...related: [unrecognized character in header of csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69844368/unrecognized-character-in-header-of-csv)

Comment: Anyhow -- please either delete the question or [edit] enough information in to let someone else answer it referring only to the question text itself (as far as I know, we don't have a "how do I ignore a byte order marker from a `while read` loop in zsh?" question on the site yet).

Comment: I'm guessing that in the zsh -x log it was printed inside `$''` quoting, as in, `$'\ufeffImage1.jpg'`, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

zsh provides a parameter expansion (also available in POSIX shells) to remove a prefix: `${var#prefix}` will expand to `$var` with `prefix` removed from the front of the string.

zsh also, like ksh93 and bash, supports ANSI C-like string syntax: `$'\ufeff'` refers to the Unicode sequence for a BOM.

Combining these, one can refer to `${filename#$'\ufeff'}` to refer to the content of `$filename` but with the Unicode sequence for a BOM removed if it's present at the front.

The below also makes some changes for better performance, more reliable behavior with odd filenames, and compatibility with non-zsh shells.

```
#!/bin/zsh
red='\033[0;31m'
color_Off='\033[0m'

csvfile=$1
imgpath=$2

while IFS=, read -r filename rurl; do
    filename=${filename#$'\ufeff'}
    if ! [ -f "${imgpath}/${filename}" ]; then
        printf '%s %bMISSING%b\n' "$filename" "$red" "$color_Off"
    fi
done <"$csvfile"
```

Notes on changes unrelated to the specific fix:

- Replacing `echo -e` with `printf` lets us pick which specific variables get escape sequences expanded: `%s` for filenames means backslashes and other escapes in them are unmodified, whereas `%b` for `$red` and `$color_Off` ensures that we *do* process highlighting for them.
- Replacing `cat $csvfile |` with `< "$csvfile"` avoids the overhead of starting up a separate `cat` process, and ensures that your `while read` loop is run in the same shell as the rest of your script rather than a subshell (which may or may not be an issue for zsh, but *is* a problem with bash when run without the non-default `lastpipe` flag).
- `echo -n` isn't reliable as a noop: some shells print `-n` as output, and [the POSIX `echo` standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), by marking behavior when `-n` is present as undefined, permits this. If you need a noop, `:` or `true` is a better choice; but in this case we can just invert the test and move the `else` path into the truth path.