# Python pandas read_clipboard

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

Having been trying to decode the problem but haven't gotten any solution.
It's all about reading text from the clipboard and it's showing me a strange character instead of a pure text which was copied into  the clipboard:

[image: it's exactly like this]

Snippet used;

```
  tex=pd.read_clipboard(header=None,engine='python',
                            index_col=None,
                            encoding='utf-8') 
  tex=tex.replace(np.nan,'',regex=True)
  tex=tex.to_numpy()
  print(tex)
```

Comment: What's in your clipboard when you run the code?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974765/weird-characters-added-to-first-column-name-after-reading-a-toad-exported-csv-fi?rq=1 This could be caused by an application adding a byte-order mark to the copied text.

Comment: @richardec text copied from an entry box of tkinter.