# Python program for matching file names and copying them into a zip is not finding a specific file?

Tags: python, regex

i have a pogram that takes the items from a CSV into a string and searches a given area for those files, and if found it zips them up and places them wherever the user chooses.

for whatever reason there is a specific file that i KNOW it can pick up is just being skipped over.

the filename is is missing is FP14427P-PL_2

the CSV contains FP14427P-PL without the _2 but i know it can pick it up as it is not strict on the search for text.

code below:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog
import os
import zipfile
from threading import Thread

class FileSearchApp:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("File Search App")
        self.master.geometry("400x700")  # Set the initial size of the window (increased height)

        style = ttk.Style()
        style.configure("TButton",
                        font=("Arial", 12),
                        padding=10,
                        foreground="black",  # Black text color
                        background="#4CAF50")  # Green background color

        self.csv_label = tk.Label(master, text="Select CSV file:")
        self.csv_label.pack(pady=10)

        self.csv_browse_button = ttk.Button(master, text="Browse CSV", command=self.browse_csv)
        self.csv_browse_button.pack(pady=10)

        self.path_label = tk.Label(master, text="Select search path:")
        self.path_label.pack(pady=10)

        self.path_browse_button = ttk.Button(master, text="Browse Path", command=self.browse_path)
        self.path_browse_button.pack(pady=10)

        self.save_label = tk.Label(master, text="Select save location for zip:")
        self.save_label.pack(pady=10)

        self.save_entry = tk.Entry(master, width=40)
        self.save_entry.pack(pady=10)

        self.save_browse_button = ttk.Button(master, text="Browse Save Location", command=self.browse_save_location)
        self.save_browse_button.pack(pady=10)

        self.search_button = ttk.Button(master, text="Search", command=self.start_search)
        self.search_button.pack(pady=10)

        self.progress_label = tk.Label(master, text="")
        self.progress_label.pack(pady=5)

        self.progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(master, orient="horizontal", length=200, mode="indeterminate")
        self.progress_bar.pack(pady=10)

        self.result_label = tk.Label(master, text="")
        self.result_label.pack(pady=10)

        self.csv_path = ""
        self.search_path = ""
        self.save_location = ""

    def browse_csv(self):
        file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("CSV Files", "*.csv")])
        if file_path:
            self.csv_path = file_path
            self.csv_label.config(text=f"Selected CSV file: {os.path.basename(file_path)}")

    def browse_path(self):
        directory_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
        if directory_path:
            self.search_path = directory_path
            self.path_label.config(text=f"Selected search path: {directory_path}")

    def browse_save_location(self):
        save_location = filedialog.askdirectory()
        if save_location:
            self.save_location = save_location
            self.save_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.save_entry.insert(0, save_location)

    def start_search(self):
        self.result_label.config(text="")
        self.progress_label.config(text="Searching...")
        self.progress_bar.start()
        search_thread = Thread(target=self.search_and_zip)
        search_thread.start()

    def search_and_zip(self):
        try:
            if not self.csv_path or not self.search_path or not self.save_location:
                self.show_result("Please select CSV file, search path, and save location.")
                return

            search_query = self.search_path
            if not search_query:
                self.show_result("Please enter a search path.")
                return

            # Read CSV file and extract filenames
            with open(self.csv_path, 'r') as csv_file:
                csv_items = {line.strip() for line in csv_file.readlines() if line.strip()}

            matches = []
            not_found = set(csv_items)  # To store names of files not found, initialize with all expected names

            for root, _, files in os.walk(search_query):
                for file in files:
                    for item in csv_items:
                        if item.lower() in file.lower():
                            matches.append(os.path.join(root, file))
                            not_found.discard(item)
                            break

            if matches:
                zip_filename = os.path.join(self.save_location, 'found_files.zip')
                with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_filename, 'w') as zip_file:
                    for match in matches:
                        zip_file.write(match, os.path.relpath(match, search_query))

                result_text = f"Found {len(matches)} matching files.\n"
                result_text += f"Zip file created: {zip_filename}"
                self.show_result(result_text)
            else:
                self.show_result("No matching files found.")

            if not_found:
                not_found_filename = os.path.join(self.save_location, 'not_found_files.txt')
                with open(not_found_filename, 'w') as not_found_file:
                    not_found_file.write("\n".join(not_found))
                print(f"List of not found files saved to: {not_found_filename}")
                self.show_result(f"List of not found files saved to: {not_found_filename}")

            # Print out filenames for debugging
            print("Matched files:")
            for match in matches:
                print(match)

        except Exception as e:
            error_message = f"An error occurred: {str(e)}"
            print(error_message)  # Print error message for debugging
            self.show_result(error_message)
        finally:
            self.progress_bar.stop()
            self.progress_label.config(text="")

    def show_result(self, message):
        self.result_label.config(text=message)


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = FileSearchApp(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

i've tried debugging to see if maybe there is something weird going on with the regex or if maybe because it has a hyphen in it but just not quite sure.

Comment: Please provide only the **relevant** part of the code - the whole UI thing is just useless here, and we don't want to have to scroll through that much code to find *the* problematic part. See how to create a [mre].

Comment: @ThierryLathuille how about stop being a lazy bones and fix my code, thank you!

Comment: I took the time to write a comment for you in order to help you improve your question - you might want to remember that you don't pay us, so you'd better help us help you if you really want someone here to help you....

Comment: And for your future questions, a bit of explanation about what is expected of SO users: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: @ThierryLathuille i fixed it myself, it was this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974765/weird-characters-added-to-first-column-name-after-reading-a-toad-exported-csv-fi

Comment: @user23866095 I hope you behave better IRL, an attitude like that is quickly going to get you excluded from significant parts of life