# PHP adds special character to string, making query invalid

Tags: php, mysql

In my script I loop through an array and create a single INSERT INTO string from it, with multiple values. When executing I get this error:

```
.. right syntax to use near 'ï»¿INSERT INTO
```

As you can see, PHP adds a strange character in front of the string. The string is created with

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table(`ItemID`, `Quantity`) VALUES "; 

foreach($articles as $item) 
{ 
    $sql .= "(".$item['ItemID'].",".$item['Quantity']."),"; 
} 

$sql = substr($sql, 0, -1); // to eliminate the trailing ","

$sql .= ";";
```

Why does PHP add this character and how can I detect and remove it? The file is saved as UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: The character looks like a Byte Order Mark, as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3255993/1426891).

Comment: The file is saved as UTF-8 without BOM. But I thought BOM is only added to the beginning of files, why does PHP add it to a string value? The project consists of much more files, and everyone works just fine with strings and querys.

Comment: The `BOM` is not visible. It's possible (improbable, but possible) that the code contains the 3-bytes BOM sequence between the opening quote and `INSERT`. Delete the `INSERT` keyword together with the quote before it then type the deleted characters again and see what happens. PHP doesn't add characters in the queries.

Comment: Tried that a dozen times, nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

The characters you're seeing are probably a misread [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), a Unicode character (U+FEFF) meant to indicate which [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) is used for UTF-16 files. To quote [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8):

> The UTF-8 representation of the BOM is the byte sequence `0xEF,0xBB,0xBF`. A text editor or web browser interpreting the text as ISO-8859-1 or CP1252 will display the characters `ï»¿` for this.

Though your PHP *file* may easily be saved without a BOM, that doesn't mean one isn't prepended to your *query*. Without seeing how your `$sql` variable is passed into `mysql`, though, I only have a few guesses:

- Byte order doesn't matter in UTF-8, but [BOMs are valid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) and are sometimes used to identify a string as Unicode. You may need to manually instruct MySQL to interpret your string as UTF-8 instead of ISO-8859-1 (using [`mysql_set_charset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) or equivalent). Setting client and server encodings explicitly is a good idea anyway.
- If this is a machine-specific problem, also check the versions of PHP and your MySQL client and server are the same as production (or your other machines). It is very plausible for a default encoding to evolve over server/client versions, or for some servers (but not others) to detect a byte order mark and automatically switch to UTF-8.
- If your query is saved to a file temporarily (e.g. for batch execution or caching) you may find it written with a Byte Order Mark automatically.

Comment: The $sql is passed just as it is with mysqli_query. No prepared statements, just "INSERT INTO table(field1, field2) VALUES (x1, y1),(x2,y2).." etc. I set the character set of the mysqli connection to UTF-8 with both "SET NAMES utf-8" and "SET CHARARCTER SET utf-8", but nothing changes. Checked the code on other machines, same result. I edited the query "making-of" in my first post.

Answer (score 0):

By adding this line worked for me

```
$string_query = str_replace("\xEF\xBB\xBF", "", $string_query);
```