# Why I am getting � at the start of ajax response?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, codeigniter

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
$('#tags').select2({
tags: true,
tokenSeparators: [','],
createSearchChoice: function (term) {
    return {
        id: $.trim(term),
        text: $.trim(term) + ' (new tag)'
    };
},
ajax: {
    url: '<?php echo site_url('home_page/get_tags');?>',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: function(term, page) {
        return {
            q: term
        };
    },
    results: function(data, page) {
        alert(data);
        return {

            results: data

        };
    }
},
```

My controller:

```
public function get_tags()
{            
    $data=  $this->common_model->get_tags_list();

    $d = json_encode($data);
    echo $d;
}
```

The AJAX response I am getting:

> ����������[{"tag_id":"1","tag_list":"#follow"},{"tag_id":"2","tag_list":"#all_shots"},{"tag_id":"3","tag_list":"#instago"},{"tag_id":"4","tag_list":"#style"},{"tag_id":"5","tag_list":"#TFLers"},{"tag_id":"6","tag_list":"#follow"},{"tag_id":"7","tag_list":"#all_shots"},{"tag_id":"8","tag_list":"#instago"},{"tag_id":"9","tag_list":"#style"},{"tag_id":"10","tag_list":"#TFLers"},{"tag_id":"11","tag_list":"#igers"},{"tag_id":"12","tag_list":"#girl"},{"tag_id":"13","tag_list":"#colorful"},{"tag_id":"14","tag_list":"#nature"},{"tag_id":"15","tag_list":"#tree"},{"tag_id":"16","tag_list":"#green"},{"tag_id":"17","tag_list":"#skylovers"},{"tag_id":"18","tag_list":"shoes"},{"tag_id":"19","tag_list":"scaper"}]

I want to remove these characters and get the response only which is sending from controller like below:

> [{"tag_id":"1","tag_list":"#follow"},{"tag_id":"2","tag_list":"#all_shots"},{"tag_id":"3","tag_list":"#instago"},{"tag_id":"4","tag_list":"#style"},{"tag_id":"5","tag_list":"#TFLers"},{"tag_id":"6","tag_list":"#follow"},{"tag_id":"7","tag_list":"#all_shots"},{"tag_id":"8","tag_list":"#instago"},{"tag_id":"9","tag_list":"#style"},{"tag_id":"10","tag_list":"#TFLers"},{"tag_id":"11","tag_list":"#igers"},{"tag_id":"12","tag_list":"#girl"},{"tag_id":"13","tag_list":"#colorful"},{"tag_id":"14","tag_list":"#nature"},{"tag_id":"15","tag_list":"#tree"},{"tag_id":"16","tag_list":"#green"},{"tag_id":"17","tag_list":"#skylovers"},{"tag_id":"18","tag_list":"shoes"},{"tag_id":"19","tag_list":"scaper"}]

Comment: Is there any PHP output handler registered?

Comment: at a guess its the UTF8 byte order mark, save the file without the byte order mark http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255993/how-do-i-remove-%C3%AF-from-the-beginning-of-a-file

Comment: what are you getting when you `die($d);`

Comment: @NullPoiиteя nothing because $id is not defined.

Comment: sorry , what are you getting when you die($d) ?

Comment: @exussum what file ... ?

Comment: die($d); getting same response as i mention in problem

Comment: what ever file is generating the ajax reply

Comment: $d = json_encode($data);
           ob_clean();
           ob_end_clean(); // number of calls depends on number of stacked output handlers,
        echo $d;
        exit(); it's work for me guys thanks

Answer (score 3):

It is happening because `white spaces`. `trim` it before returning the response. Try with -

```
echo trim($d);
```

**Update**

This could also help but i am not sure about the reason the `�`s on the output as some functions are generating the data and the data might coming from database, so somewhere those characters are prepended to the data -

```
echo trim($a, '�');
```

Try -

```
$a = "����������<pre class";
echo trim($a, '�');
```

Output -

```
<pre class
```

Comment: @Asif_SE can you echo the string on php side (not after getting the response) and display the output?

Comment: $d is the result of `json_encode` php function. This is not generating these chars at all, thus a "trim" will not solve the problem. Furthermore, it's not whitespaces but some 8-bit chars.

Comment: @AxelAmthor those characters are prepended to `$d`.

Comment: so any suggestion plz I am tied to remove these characters

Comment: @sgtBOSE ... and what are you telling me? The OPs question is how to get rid of them, implying that someone knows where they are coming from. "trimming" would only cure symptoms and doesn't help at all in this case either.

Comment: using var_dum($d)  getting this response ����������<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'[{&quot
;tag_id&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;tag_list&quot;:&quot;#follow&quot;},{&quot;tag_id&quot;:&quot;2&quot
;,&quot;tag_list&quot;:&quot;#all_shots&quot;},{&quot;tag_id&quot;:&quot;3&quot;,&quot;tag_list&quot
;:&quot;#instago&quot;},{&quot;tag_id&quot;:&quot;4&quot;,&quot;tag_list&quot;:&quot;#style&quot;},{
&quot;tag_id&quot;:&quot;5&quot;,&quot;tag_list&quot;:&quot;#TFLers&quot;}

Comment: var_dump($data) showing this response ����������<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=19)</i>
  0 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> 
    <b>array</b> <i>(size=2)</i>
      'tag_id' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'1'</font
> <i>(length=1)</i>
      'tag_list' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'#follow'
</font> <i>(length=7)</i>

Comment: Then you should add the code of `get_tags_list()` also.

Comment: public function get_tags_list()
        {
            
            $q=$this->db->query("Select * from tags");
  return $q->result_array();

Comment: please try this: `$test ="TESTSTRING"; var_dump($test);`and post the output please.

Comment: @sgtBOSE this is nonsense, sorry.

Comment: @AxelAmthor so what sense do you have to solve this? Please do it then.

Comment: $test ="TESTSTRING"; var_dump($test);     response of this ....����������<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'TESTSTRING'
</font> <i>(length=10)</i>
</pre>

Comment: $d = json_encode($data);
           ob_clean();
           ob_end_clean(); // number of calls depends on number of stacked output handlers,
        echo $d;
        exit(); it's work for me

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with the code above.

Since these chars do appear, they are prepended *after* the `echo $d` - which might be caused by an output handler globally registered in PHP.

Or something weired within the web server (nginx, apache, ...?).

I would recommend to check that first before fiddling around in obviously proper three-liners.

**EDIT**:

It seems, that everything what PHP is spitting out anyhow is getting surrounded by some HTML-Tags:

> using var_dum($d) getting this response `����������<pre
>   class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>string</small> <font
>   color='#cc0000'>'[{&quot` ....

This indicates, that there **IS** an output handler and any solution which tries to solve this by modifying $d will / must fail.

**EDIT 2**:

you might try:

```
 ....
 ob_end_clean();
 ob_end_clean();  // number of calls depends on number of stacked output handlers,
 echo $d;
 exit(0);
```

Comment: I am working with codeigniter any suggestion to fix output handler ?

Comment: unfortunatelly not with ci, but this `print_r(ob_list_handlers());` might be a starting point

Comment: Hello Axel Amthor .  $d = json_encode($data);
           ob_clean();
           ob_end_clean(); // number of calls depends on number of stacked output handlers,
        echo $d;
        exit(); it's work for me many thanks man