# Wordpress Plugin - impleCode eCommerce Product Catalog Import errors

Tags: wordpress, csv

I have been trying to use the sample CSV file from my wordpress plugin called "impleCode eCommerce Product Catalog" to import products and I've been having a lot of trouble doing so. When I download the sample file, the first A1 column/row has:

ï»¿"Image URL";"Product Name";"Product Price";"Product Categories";"Short Description";"Long Description"

It seems like those weird characters in the beginning could be causing an issue. I decided to open it with a text editor and create each line item and then saving the file but keeping the extension as CSV. Sometimes it wont update any new products and sometimes it will add some products but not the others.

I also tried adding a semicolon to the end of the long desc since it's missing and I'm still having the same issue. I feel like there is something wrong with the sample file.

Is there a way to create a proper CSV file where each cell has the different attributes and upload it that way? In other words, is there a way that I can make row "A" be used for image urls, "B" for Product Name and So on. Then go to column 2 for the next product and do the same thing? I would think that this is a better way to create a proper CSV file for importing products and it doesn't seem to be working as it should.

Any suggestions on why this may be happening?

Here is a link to the sample file I am downloading directly from the plugin: [Sample Import CSV File](http://www.securitycameraking.com/images_templ/simple-products.csv)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255993/how-do-i-remove-%C3%AF-from-the-beginning-of-a-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issues I was having. First thing I caught that I was doing wrong was adding a semicolon to the end of each line. I didn't notice that the final item on that list only needed to be escaped using a return.

The second thing I did was open the CSV file with TextEdit and included "sep=;" to the top of the file and saved. This will tell excel that each item is escaped with a semicolon and will properly align them in separate cells instead of putting the whole line item in one cell.