# To remove ï»¿ from file in php

Tags: php

I want to remove ï»¿ from my file .This is appear from the top of my file.If I remove with preg_replace,remaining ï.I cann't json decode to convert into array.How can I solve it.Please help me,it is very difficult for me now.

**This is my file**

```
' ï»¿ {"status":"1","mobile_user":[{"id":"1","name":"saa","phone_no":"09978784963","activate_code":"","deposit":"0","created":"2015-05-29 00:00:00","updated":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","status":"1"}]}'
```

Comment: Seems the file encoding has problems. Can you double check?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255993/how-do-i-remove-%C3%AF-from-the-beginning-of-a-file

Answer (score 0):

save your php file as utf-8 without bom, using notepad++