# How to remove ï»¿ from a PHP page

Tags: php, html

I'm developing a small website and to include the header in using PHP's `include()` function. However directly before any code brought in from the include, there's this weird  ï»¿ on the page.

Here's code for page where it's happening

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Things and Stuff | Source Files</title>
    <!-- Style Sheets/Scripts/Misc Stuff -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/gmod.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/alerts.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/cycle.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<?php include('./utilities/header.php'); ?>

<!-- rest of the page from here down... -->
```

**EDIT W/ SOLUTION**

I figured it out thanks to help from below. 
To fix I opened the file in Notepad++, set it to PHP, and at the top under Encoding, selected ANSI (found that was = to UTF-8 w/o BOM) and it worked!

Comment: Please show the contents of the header file.

Comment: This is the best for you: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255993/how-do-i-remove-%C3%AF-from-the-beginning-of-a-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255993/how-do-i-remove-%C3%AF-from-the-beginning-of-a-file)

Comment: It has to be in header file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your header file contains a Byte Order Mark header, not clearly visible be text editors which understand them and do not print them.

Compilers/parser, on the other hand, expect full ASCII, and don't understand BOM marks.

Solution: Remove the 3 first bytes of your header file with an hex editor  or a text editor set to ASCII or UTF8 without BOM encoding and it will work.

below screenshot of the file encoded in UTF8 with BOM with 3 first chars highlighted (using frHed)

[image]

If I remove the 3 first bytes it works.
OR: open with Notepad++ and change encoding to `ASCII`, save, voilà.

Comment: Doesn't the byte order mark usually mean each character will be multiple bytes, meaning a lot of null bytes in the file?

Comment: That will by UTF16 format. In that case, removing the 3 first bytes won't work, but changing the encoding to ASCII or UTF8-noBOM also works.

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much! I used the option at the bottom of changing with Notepad++

Answer (score 1):

Check your PHP file encoding. Try using UTF8 without boom, and make sure your php has no empty spaces at the top of the file.