# nodejs readFileSync output is garbage

Tags: node.js

heres my code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var corpus = fs.readFileSync('./TXT/tragedies/Macbeth.txt', 'utf8');

console.log(corpus.toString());
```

When I run this I get a bunch of nonsense unicode characters:

```
00\r\u0000\n\u0000<\u0000/\u0000S\u0000T\u0000A\u0000G\u0000E\u0000 \u0000D\u0000I\u0000R\u0000>\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000<\u0000M\u0000A\u0000L\u0000C\u0000O\u0000L\u0000M\u0000>\u0000\t\u0000<\u00009\u00009\u0000%\u0000>\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000\t\u0000W\u0000e\u0000 \u0000s\u0000h\u0000a\u0000l\u0000l\u0000 \u0000n\u0000o\u0000t\u0000 \u0000s\u0000p\u0000e\u0000n\u0000d\u0000 \u0000a\u0000 \u0000l\u0000a\u0000r\u0000g\u0000e\u0000 \u0000e\u0000x\u0000p\u0000e\u0000n\u0000s\u0000e\u0000 \u0000o\u0000f\u0000 \u0000t\u0000i\u0000m\u0000e\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000\t\u0000B\u0000e\u0000f\u0000o\u0000r\u0000e\u0000 \u0000w\u0000e\u0000 \u0000r\u0000e\u0000c\u0000k\u0000o\u0000n\u0000 \u0000w\u0000i\u0000t\u0000h\u0000 \u0000y\u0000o\u0000u\u0000r\u0000 \u0000s\u0000e\u0000v\u0000e\u0000r\u0000a\u0000l\u0000 \u0000l\u0000o\u0000v\u0000e\u0000s\u0000,\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000\t\u0000A\u0000n\u0000d\u0000 \u0000m\u0000a\u0000k\u0000e\u0000 \u0000u\u0000s\u0000 \u0000e\u0000v\u0000e\u0000n\u0000 \u0000w\u0000i\u0000t\u0000h\u0000 \u0000y\u0000o\u0000u\u0000.\u0000 \u0000M\u0000y\u0000 \u0000t\u0000h\u0000a\u0000n\u0000e\u0000s\u0000 \u0000a\u0000n\u0000d\u0000 \u0000k\u0000i\u0000n\u0000s\u0000m\u0000e\u0000n\u0000,\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000\t\u0000H\u0000e\u0000n\u0000c\u0000e\u0000f\u0000o\u0000r\u0000t\u0000h\u0000 \u0000b\u0000e\u0000 \u0000e\u0000a\u0000r\u0000l\u0000s\u0000,\u0000 \u0000t\u0000h\u0000e\u0000 \u0000f\u0000i\u0000r\u0000s\u0000t\u0000 \u0000t\u0000h\u0000a\u0000t\u0000 \u0000e\u0000v\u0000e\u0000r\u0000 \u0000S\u0000c\u0000o\u0000t\u0000l\u0000a\u0000n\u0000d\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000\t\u0000I\u0000n\u0000 \u0000s\u0000u\u0000c\u0000h\u0000 \u0000a\u0000n\u0000 \u0000h\u0000o\u0000n\u0000o\u0000u\u0000r\u0000 \u0000n\u0000a\u0000m\u0000\'\u0000d\u0000.\u0000 \u0000W\u0000h\u0000a\u0000t\u0000\'\u0000s\u0000 \u0000m\u0000o\u0000r\u0000e\u0000 \u0000t\u0000o\u0000 \u0000d\u0000o\u0000,\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000\t\u0000W\u0000h\u0000i\u0000c\u0000h\u0000 \u0000w\u0000o\u0000u\u0000l\u0000d\u0000 \u0000b\u0000e\u0000 \u0000p\u0000l\u0000a\u0000n\u0000t\u0000e\u0000d\u0000 \u0000n\u0000e\u0000w\u0000l\u0000y\u0000 \u0000w\u0000i\u0000t\u0000h\u0000 \u0000t\u0000h\u0000e\u0000 \u0000t\u0000i\u0000m\u0000e\u0000,\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000\t\u0000A\u0000s\u0000 \u0000c\u0000a\u0000l\u0000l\u0000i\u0000n\u0000g\u0000 \u0000h\u0000o\u0000m\u0000e\u0000 \u0000o\u0000u\u0000r\u0000 \u0000e\u0000x\u0000i\u0000l\u0000\'\u0000d\u0000 \u0000f\u0000r\u0000i\u0000e\u0000n\u0000d\u0000s\u0000 \u0000a\u0000b\u0000r\u0000o\u0000a\u0000d\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000\t\u0000T\u0000h\u0000a\u0000t\u0000 \u0000f\u0000l\u0000e\u0000d\u0000 \u0000t\u0000h\u0000e\u0000 \u0000s\u0000n\u0000a\u0000r\u0000e\u0000s\u0000 \u0000o\u0000f\u0000 \u0000w\u0000a\u0000t\u0000c\u0000h\u0000f\u0000u\u0000l\u0000 \u0000t\u0000y\u0000r\u0000a\u0000n\u0000n\u0000y\u0000;\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000\t\u0000P\u0000r\u0000o\u0000d\u0000u\u0000c\u0000i\u0000n\u0000g\u0000 \u0000f\u0000o\u0000r\u0000t\u0000h\u0000 \u0000t\u0000h\u0000e\u0000 \u0000c\u0000r\u0000u\u0000e\u0000l\u0000 \u0000m\u0000i\u0000n\u0000i\u0000s\u0000t\u0000e\u0000r\u0000s\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000\t\u0000O\u0000f\u0000 \u0000t\u0000h\u0000i\u0000s\u0000 \u0000d\u0000e\u0000a\u0000d\u0000 \u0000b\u0000u\u0000t\u0000c\u0000h\u0000e\u0000r\u0000 \u0000a\u0000n\u0000d\u0000 \u0000h\u0000i\u0000s\u0000 \u0000f\u0000i\u0000e\u0000n\u0000d\u0000-\u0000l\u0000i\u0000k\u0000e\u0000 \u0000q\u0000u\u0000e\u0000e\u0000n\u0000,\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000\t\u0000W\u0000h\u0000o\u0000,\u0000 \u0000a\u0000s\u0000 \u0000\'\u0000t\u0000i\u0000s\u0000 \u0000t\u0000h\u0000o\u0000u\u0000g\u0000h\u0000t\u0000,\u0000 \u0000b\u0000y\u0000 \u0000s\u0000e\u0000l\u0000f\u0000 \u0000a\u0000n\u0000d\u0000 \u0000v\u0000i\u0000o\u0000l\u0000e\u0000n\u0000t\u0000 \u0000h\u0000a\u0000n\u0000d\u0000s\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000\t\u0000T\u0000o\u0000o\u0000k\u0000 \u0000o\u0000f\u0000f\u0000 \u0000h\u0000e\u0000r\u0000 \u0000l\u0000i\u0000f\u0000e\u0000;\u0000 \u0000t\u0000h\u0000i\u0000s\u0000,\u0000 \u0000a\u0000n\u0000d\u0000 \u0000w\u0000h\u0000a\u0000t\u0000 \u0000n\u0000e\u0000e\u0000d\u0000f\u0000u\u0000l\u0000 \u0000e\u0000l\u0000s\u0000e\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000\t\u0000T\u0000h\u0000a\u0000t\u0000 \u0000c\u0000a\u0000l\u0000l\u0000s\u0000 \u0000u\u0000p\u0000o\u0000n\u0000 \u0000u\u0000s\u0000,\u0000 \u0000b\u0000y\u0000 \u0000t\u0000h\u0000e\u0000 \u0000g\u0000r\u0000a\u0000c\u0000e\u0000 \u0000o\u0000f\u0000 \u0000G\u0000r\u0000a\u0000c\u0000e\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000\t\u0000W\u0000e\u0000 \u0000w\u0000i\u0000l\u0000l\u0000 \u0000p\u0000e\u0000r\u0000f\u0000o\u0000r\u0000m\u0000 \u0000i\u0000n\u0000 \u0000m\u0000e\u0000a\u0000s\u0000u\u0000r\u0000e\u0000,\u0000 \u0000t\u0000i\u0000m\u0000e\u0000,\u0000 \u0000a\u0000n\u0000d\u0000 \u0000p\u0000l\u0000a\u0000c\u0000e\u0000:\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000\t\u0000S\u0000o\u0000,\u0000 \u0000t\u0000h\u0000a\u0000n\u0000k\u0000s\u0000 \u0000t\u0000o\u0000 \u0000a\u0000l\u0000l\u0000 \u0000a\u0000t\u0000 \u0000o\u0000n\u0000c\u0000e\u0000 \u0000a\u0000n\u0000d\u0000 \u0000t\u0000o\u0000 \u0000e\u0000a\u0000c\u0000h\u0000 \u0000o\u0000n\u0000e\u0000,\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000\t\u0000W\u0000h\u0000o\u0000m\u0000 \u0000w\u0000e\u0000 \u0000i\u0000n\u0000v\u0000i\u0000t\u0000e\u0000 \u0000t\u0000o\u0000 \u0000s\u0000e\u0000e\u0000 \u0000u\u0000s\u0000 \u0000c\u0000r\u0000o\u0000w\u0000n\u0000\'\u0000d\u0000 \u0000a\u0000t\u0000 \u0000S\u0000c\u0000o\u0000n\u0000e\u0000.\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000<\u0000/\u0000M\u0000A\u0000L\u0000C\u0000O\u0000L\u0000M\u0000>\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000<\u0000S\u0000T\u0000A\u0000G\u0000E\u0000 \u0000D\u0000I\u0000R\u0000>\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000<\u0000F\u0000l\u0000o\u0000u\u0000r\u0000i\u0000s\u0000h\u0000.\u0000 \u0000E\u0000x\u0000e\u0000u\u0000n\u0000t\u0000.\u0000>\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000<\u0000/\u0000S\u0000T\u0000A\u0000G\u0000E\u0000 \u0000D\u0000I\u0000R\u0000>\u0000\r\u0000\n\u000
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove ï»¿ from the beginning of a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255993/how-do-i-remove-%c3%af-from-the-beginning-of-a-file)

Comment: Basically, you're file has the aBOMination that is the Byte Order Mark that some Windows software likes to use. Use UTF8 instead.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara i am using utf8...

Comment: Your reading it as utf8, which the file was not encoded as.

Comment: What is the solution?

Comment: Would be best to encode the text file as UTF8. It's way-better supported and will be about half the file size.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you don't need to transform the output of readFileSync into a string, because it's already one.

```
var fs = require('fs');                                     
var file = fs.readFileSync("file.txt", "utf8");             
console.log(file);                                          
console.log(typeof file);
```

Output:

```
  File content 
  here's a new paragraph      

  string
```

Just for info, what version of Node are you using?
What I did works on 4.4.7.