# shell - The code is correct, but it does not work

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell

Everything is normal. But it gives an error. I could not solve it.

*try.sh*:

```
#!/bin/sh

website="http://lastofdead.xyz"
ipaddress=$( ifconfig | grep -v 'eth0:' | grep -A 1 'eth0' | \
             tail -1 | cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
mlicense=$(curl -s $website/lodscript/special/lisans.php?lisans)

if [ "$mlicense" = "$ipaddress" ];
then 
    echo "Positive"
else
    echo "Negative"
fi
```

*lisans.php*:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['lisans'])) {
echo "188.166.92.168" . $_GET['lisans'];
}
?>
```

Result:

```
root@ubuntu:~# bash -x s.sh
+ website=http://lastofdead.xyz
++ cut -d ' ' -f 1
++ cut -d : -f 2
++ tail -1
++ grep -A 1 eth0
++ grep -v eth0:
++ ifconfig
+ ipaddress=188.166.92.168
++ curl -s 'http://lastofdead.xyz/lodscript/special/lisans.php?lisans'
+ mlicense=188.166.92.168
+ '[' 188.166.92.168 = 188.166.92.168 ']'
+ echo Negative
Negative
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNMNq.jpg

Comment: Maybe try to change single = with -eq operator in your condition and remove " characters?

Comment: @R.CanserYanbakan I've tried but it does not work.

Comment: @R.CanserYanbakan Neither of those suggestions is correct.

Comment: Personally I would confirm if there is any whitespace around ip addresses

Comment: Maybe not related but `if [ "$mlicense" = "$ipaddress" ];` will always give true and the semi-colon is not necessary.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the result of the `curl` call ends with a CRLF pair, resulting in the value of `mlicense` ending with a carriage return. I would expect that to show up clearly in the output of `bash -x`, though.

Comment: Are you *sure* the code you show above is the code that is actually being executed?

Comment: @chepner yes i am sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, thank you very much for posting the code.
Well, having tried to see myself the differences between the two strings, it turned out that the problem was something called [Byte Order Mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). For more info about this, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3256014.

The string returned by curl, when piping it to an hex dump, shows this:

```
$ curl -s 'http://lastofdead.xyz/lodscript/special/lisans.php?lisans'
188.166.92.168
$ curl -s 'http://lastofdead.xyz/lodscript/special/lisans.php?lisans' | xxd -c 17 -g 1 -u
0000000: EF BB BF 31 38 38 2E 31 36 36 2E 39 32 2E 31 36 38  ...188.166.92.168
```

Can you see them? Those three bytes, `0xEF,0xBB,0xBF`, are the UTF-8 representation of the BOM, and *that's* what makes the strings differ. The question page linked above shows some ways to strip it, like using `grep`, or you could pipe the curl output to `cut -c 2-`, or even through a simple substitution after the `curl` line: `mlicense="${mlicense:1}"`. And, to make sure that what we strip is the BOM, we could use two lines of substitution: `bom="$(echo -en '\xEF\xBB\xBF')"; mlicense="$(echo -n "${mlicense#${bom}}")"`, or even turn them into one: `mlicense="$(echo -n "${mlicense#$(echo -en '\xEF\xBB\xBF')}")"`.