# Bash script - Recursive Find of New lines and Carriage returns at end of files

Tags: php, bash, sed, awk, grep

I have a website that is giving me all sorts of errors, I've ran a recursive script to check for BOM headers.. but how would I do the same thing to find carriage returns and line feeds at the end of a file?

I want to check over my codebase to make sure there aren't any files with extra lines hanging out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you want to check (without remove/replace) the empty lines at the end of a file.

you can try :

```
 awk '{a=$0;}END{if(!a)print FILENAME}' file
```

this will print the file name out if there is at least one empty line at the end of the file.

for Recursion, you could use `find ... |xargs awk '...'`

**updated**

ok, I made an example, so that you could test:

```
find . -iname "*.php"|xargs -n1 awk '{a=$0;}END{if(!a)print FILENAME}'
```

the above line will check all php files recursively based on your current directory, if there is at least one empty line at the end of a php file, print the filename.

Comment: Ok trying to get this.  find '\x0' | xargs awk '{a=$0;}END{if(!a)print FILENAME}'

Comment: @Justin what did you mean? what's `find '\x0'?`

Comment: Hm I thought \x0 would be perhaps the string to search for http://code.cside.com/3rdpage/us/newLine.html

Comment: See, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204765/elegant-way-to-search-for-utf-8-files-with-bom had a snippit to find byte order mark chars in files.  I thought the patterns might be similar

Comment: @Justin see my updated answer, there is an example that you can try out.

Comment: Yep that did the trick.  Thanks..  Hope this helps track down the bug.