# Byte Order Mark causing session errors

Tags: php, session, utf-8, byte-order-mark

I have an PHP app with houndreds of files. The problem is that one or several files apparently have a BOM in them, so including them causes error when creating the session... Is there a way how to reconfigure PHP or the server or how can I get rid of the BOM? Or at least identify the source? I would prefer a PHP solution if available

Comment: How those files were created?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204765/elegant-way-to-search-for-utf-8-files-with-bom

Comment: makes no difference how they were created... @anders lindahl that's a shell script, I can't use that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to identify the files that carried BOM inside them with this script, maybe it helps someone else with the same problem in the future. Works without `eval()`.

```
function fopen_utf8 ($filename) { 
    $file = @fopen($filename, "r"); 
    $bom = fread($file, 3); 
    if ($bom != b"\xEF\xBB\xBF") 
    { 
        return false; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        return true; 
    } 
} 

function file_array($path, $exclude = ".|..|libraries", $recursive = true) { 
    $path = rtrim($path, "/") . "/"; 
    $folder_handle = opendir($path); 
    $exclude_array = explode("|", $exclude); 
    $result = array(); 
    while(false !== ($filename = readdir($folder_handle))) { 
        if(!in_array(strtolower($filename), $exclude_array)) { 
            if(is_dir($path . $filename . "/")) { 
                // Need to include full "path" or it's an infinite loop 
                if($recursive) $result[] = file_array($path . $filename . "/", $exclude, true); 
            } else { 
                if ( fopen_utf8($path . $filename) ) 
                { 
                    //$result[] = $filename; 
                    echo ($path . $filename . "<br>"); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    return $result; 
} 

$files = file_array(".");
```

Answer (score 1):

The real solution of course is to fix your editor settings (and the other team members as well) to not store files with UTF byte order mark. Read on here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2558793/43959

You could use this function to "transparently" remove the BOM before including another PHP file.

**Note: I really recommend you to fix your editor(s) / files instead of doing nasty things with `eval()` which i demonstrate here.**

**This is just a proof of concept:**

bom_test.php:

```
<?php
function bom_safe_include($file) {
        $fd = fopen($file, "r");
        // read 3 bytes to detect BOM. file read pointer is now behind BOM
        $possible_bom = fread($fd, 3);
        // if the file has no BOM, reset pointer to beginning file (0)
        if ($possible_bom !== "\xEF\xBB\xBF") {
                fseek($fd, 0);
        }
        $content = stream_get_contents($fd);
        fclose($fd);
        // execute (partial) script (without BOM) using eval
        eval ("?>$content");
        // export global vars
        $GLOBALS += get_defined_vars();
}
// include a file
bom_safe_include("test_include.php");
// test function and variable from include
test_function($test);
```

test_include.php, **with BOM at beginning**

```
test
<?php
$test = "Hello World!";
function test_function ($text) {
        echo $text, PHP_EOL;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
kaii@test$ php bom_test.php
test
Hello World!
```

Answer (score -1):

```
vim $(find . -name \*.php)
```

once inside vim:

```
:argdo :set nobomb | :w
```