# session_start() cash limit

Tags: php, session

At the first , I should say I know there is some other topics similar this topic but I couldn't solve my problem after read these topics.

So , Please go to: [LINK](http://icomp.ir/myscript) , You see an error:

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home3/icompir/public_html/myscript/index.php:1) in /home3/icompir/public_html/myscript/index.php on line 3
```

I know this error has a relation with headers and sent headers. but in the "index.php" file , headers doesn't send before "session_start();" !

you can see the code of this page:

```
<?php
include('inc.php');
session_start();
include('header.php');
?>
<title>صفحه اصلی</title>
</head>
<body><div class="body">

<?php
include('navigation.php');
include('sidebar.php');
?>
<div id="content">
<strong>در دست اجرا:</strong>
<ul>
    <li>بهینه سازی اسکریپت.</li>
    <li>اضافه کردن امکان تغییر پسورد.</li>
    <li>اضافه کردن ارسال ایمیل تایید پس از ثبت نام.</li>
    <li>تذکر هنگام ثبت نام اگر نام کاربری مشابه وجود داشت.</li>
    <li>اضافه کردن امکان پیام خصوصی.</li>
    <li>تکمیل بخش پروفایل.</li>
    <li>پیاده سازی جی کوئری و آژاکس روی قسمت های مختلف سایت ...</li>
</ul>

<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>

</div></body>
</html>
```

and if you think there are some headers in "inc.php" I say you it isn't correct. This is code of "inc.php" :

```
<?php 
include('constants.php');
require_once('functions.php');
?>
```

I was checked "contants.php" and "functions.php" too. There is no header in these files.
Also this error just show in index.php! when you login or go to 
http://icomp.ir/register.php
it doesn't show.

Do you know answere?
thank you

Comment: One of the included files are generating output, either directly through something like `print` or `echo` or by generating errors. Make sure you have turned on all error reporting so that you can see the output that is being generated. Also be sure to remove _all_ lines (blank and otherwise) before the first `<?php` at the top of each script.

Comment: I was removed code line by line. Problem was solved just when the function session_start() was removed , not when remove inclution codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
<?php
include('inc.php');
session_start();
include('header.php');
?>
```

To

```
<?php
session_start();
include('inc.php');
include('header.php');
?>
```

Comment: You need to start the session first, because it sends header data necessary to maintain the session.  If you do any sort of output, it becomes too late to send any headers.

Answer (score 1):

@KirkBackus Already made a good answer, but I would just add that if you prefer, you can also deal with this by the use of output buffers. Open a buffer as the very first thing in your script - Output will then be buffered until the script ends, which allows you to send headers (Which `session_start` relies on) in script. In cases where you may not always need to use session, this might be a more manageable approach.

```
<?php
  ob_start();
  /* ... rest of code here */
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, check the settings of your editor - if there are added BOM bytes at the begining of the UTF encoded files, disable it.

See [Byte Order Mark causing session errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646540/byte-order-mark-causing-session-errors)