# Weird character in links CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp-2.2

I'm developing a application using PHP 5.4, CakePHP 2.2.3. The problem is, in my local server (XAMPP) this error does not happen (PHP 5.4).

But in my server online, it does (PHP 5.3).

The error is that little weird character in the link:

[image]

Here: `sgc/noticias/�avascript:void(0)`

Most of the weird characters are data that are fetched through the database.

This does only happen when I use the `link` method of the `HtmlHelper`. Lets say, if I echo this:

```
echo $this->Html->link('Click me', '/pages/home', array('class' => 'button', 'target' => '_blank'));
```

I get this:

[image]

As you can see in the image: `/sgc/index/�pages/home`

If I echo this:

```
<a href="/sgc/index/pages/home" >Click me</a>
```

I get this: `/sgc/index/pages/home`

If I echo this:

```
echo $this->Html->link('Click me',array('controller'=>'pages', 'action' => 'view'), array('class' => 'button', 'target' => '_blank'));
```

I get this: `/sgc/pages/view`

I read something that this problem may be something like encoding problem, but I'm almost 100% sure all my files are encoding in UTF8 (without BOM).

Looks like this is the character: %EF%BB%BF.

Also, looking at the error log shows up this:

`2012-11-21 15:37:05 Error: [MissingActionException] Action IndexController::ï¿½index() could not be found.`

I don't think this problem could be related to the CakePHP version or some file in CakePHP lib, because I just uploaded a new CakePHP application without modifying anything (just a simple CakePHP app) and everything works fine in my online server.

The error must be in some of my files and not CakePHP.

### Update

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7478330/1446827) and have used the Total Commander to search for UTF BOM files in my project. But the results are, only images return in the search for "EF BB BF".

Comment: `"\xEF\xBB\xBF"` is a UTF-8 byte-order mark, no question about it.

Comment: So you saying that maybe some file is encoding as UTF8 with BOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the problem! A really big thanks to you guys that helped me out thinking.

To go to the point, the code that was giving me those weird character is this:

```
public function url($url = null, $full = false) {

    if(!isset($url['plugin'])) {
        $url['plugin'] = null;
    }

    return parent::url($url, $full);
}
```

It was inside the class `AppHelper`. But why?

My application is divided into modules, which means that a module = plugin. I have many plugins inside my application. Sometimes when I was inside a plugin page (like News, or Blog), and I want to link to a controller that is part of the application and not part of the plugin, I always have to set `plugin => ""` so CakePHP would know that I want a controller that was is not part of the plugin;

Example: when I use the `HtmlHelper::link` or even the `HtmlHelper::url`:

```
echo $this->Html->link('All users', array('plugin' => '', 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'));
```

This would echo the right link, that will point to the `Users controller` and `index action`.

But, if I use this (without setting `plugin => ""`):

```
echo $this->Html->link('All users', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'));
```

It was pointing me to a `Users controller` inside my plugin.

I did not wanted to declare it every time (`plugin => ""`) so inside the `AppHelper::url` I simple put this routine: If there is no `plugin => ""` in the `$url` set `plugin` to null.

But this was causing me this weird characters in all URLS that was constructed using `HtmlHelper::url` or `HtmlHelper::link`.

I've changed this function to this now:

```
public function url($url = null, $full = false) {

    if (is_array($url)) {
        if(!isset($url['plugin'])) {
            $url['plugin'] = "";
        }    
    }
    return parent::url($url, $full);
}
```

And all working fine.

Answer (score 2):

`"\xEF\xBB\xBF"` is a UTF-8 byte-order mark, no question about it.

Since it's always at the beginning of the `link` argument, here are some possibilities off the top of my head:

1. Whereever you have configured the base paths (e.g. `/sgc/index`, `/sgc/noticias`), you have a stray trailing BOM.
2. The `link()` helper itself is encoding the supplied input to utf-8 (e.g., `'/pages/home'`) and mistakenly including a BOM.

I would go straight to the `HTML::link()` code and trace through it, looking for calls to `iconv` or `mb_*` functions. Most likely those libraries are being used under the hood and are somehow incorrectly configured to emit a BOM as you would when writing a file.

Answer (score 1):

It does seem to be a problem with conflicting encodings. Check that in **app/config/core.php** you have the following, it should be there since it's the default:

```
Configure::write('App.encoding', 'UTF-8');
```

Then in your views specify the `charset` in the `<head>` like this:

```
<head>
    <?php echo $html->charset(); ?>
</head>
```

---

**EDIT**

The [`link()`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/View/Helper/HtmlHelper.php#L332) method does some processing on the `URL` it receives before generating the link:

```
$url = $this->url($url); // Line 335
```

The [`url()`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/View/Helper.php#L241) method then uses the [`Router::url()`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Routing/Router.php#L745) static method and the global [`h()`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/basics.php#L165) function:

```
return h(Router::url($url, $full));
```

The `Router::url()` method doesn't seem to be doing anything related with encoding and the `h()` function just uses PHP's `htmlspecialchars()`:

```
return htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES, ($charset) ? $charset : $defaultCharset, $double);
```

I'm at a loss here, but maybe these trailing might help someone track down the cause for the character.

Comment: Yes, in my `core.php` I have the App.enconding config and in my `default.ctp` layout also have the <?php echo $this->Html->charset(); ?>. It's very strange, because this is not a problem in PHP 5.4.

Comment: See if `mbstring.func_overload` php setting is enabled. Perhaps the `substr()` function invocation in `Router::url()` (which removes the leading `/` from your argument) is silently using `mb_substr()`

Comment: @Fuhrmann What if you don't include the leading `/` in the URL supplied to the `link()` method?

Comment: @juan.facorro Good idea, but I did this right now, and the BOM character just changed the position: /sgc/index/�ages/home

Comment: @Fuhrmann Could it be possible that the uploading to the server is changing the encoding of files? Have you tried downloading the file from the server and comparing it with the original (using a text editor that lets you view file in HEX)?

Comment: @juan.facorro I just found what was the problem. I'll post the answer in a few minutes. Big thanks to you and the other guys.