# Check if PHP file is corrupted

Tags: php, file, corruption

is there a way to check by using a command into terminal,recursively into folders, if a PHP file is corrupted?
Thank you very much.

In my case, for corruption i mean bad encoding that could create problems with PHP interpreting.

Comment: If by "corrupted" you mean "PHP files with syntax errors", then you can use `php -l`.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15157/how-to-check-if-a-file-is-corrupt-or-not

Comment: Define corrupted please! Sysntax errors? Semantical errors? bad encoding?

Comment: If your version control system says it's not the same as the one you checked out anymore?

Comment: In my case, for corruption i mean bad encoding that could create problems with PHP interpreting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was caused by the Byte Order Mark in my files.
Used this answer to fix everything [Elegant way to search for UTF-8 files with BOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204765/elegant-way-to-search-for-utf-8-files-with-bom)

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by corrupted? I assume you mean syntax error?

You can check for syntax errors in a terminal with:

```
php -l file.php
```

You can use `find` to search recursively and check all php files:

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec php -l {} \;
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Worth noting you need to enable `display_errors` for CLI PHP to see detailed error message, otherwise all you get will be rather useless.