# Error: My Drupal 7 is adding the character ' at the begining of json Services output

Tags: json, rest, service, module, drupal-7

My Drupal 7 is adding the character ' at the begining of JSON output (Generated by Service Module, rest server) and this is fail when eval with https://jsonlint.com

The sample url, to recreate this issue can be: http://####/api/node/20430

This problem affect when I try to consume this output in developing app Fail also.

Any help please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your link. The problem is not with ' character.

When you check your json string in firebug you can see a special character "&#65279" in your json output at the beginning of your json output.

You can refer [Why is &#65279; appearing in my HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691771/why-is-65279-appearing-in-my-html)

The first answer will fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks your for your help, I use this to search and remove (use carefully):      You can use grep to find them and Perl to strip them out like so:
$ grep -rl $'\xEF\xBB\xBF' . | xargs perl -i -pe 's{\xEF\xBB\xBF}{}' from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204765/elegant-way-to-search-for-utf-8-files-with-bom